# Exclude results from Elastic Search based on field content

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I use FOQElasticaBundle to integrate Elastic Search into my Symfony2 project. I have an entity called `Recipe`, this entity has property `$draft` that indicates that the recipe is not complete yet. I want to exclude recipes that has the property `$draft = 1` from Elastic Search results.

This is part of my foq_elastica configuration:

```
...
types:
    chef:
        mappings:
            surname: {boost: 5}
            name: {boost: 4}
            nbLikes: { index: not_analyzed }
            nbFollowers: { index: not_analyzed }
            persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: Interacso\ApiBundle\Entity\Chef
            identifier: id
            provider: ~
            finder: ~
            listener: ~
    recipe:
        mappings:
            name: {boost: 100}
            chefName: {boost: 10}
            chefSurname: {boost: 10}
            bookNames: {boost: 5}
            ingredientNames: {boost: 2}
            tagNames: {boost: 2}
        persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: Interacso\ApiBundle\Entity\Recipe
            identifier: id
            provider: ~
            finder: ~
            listener: ~
....
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer by myself, if someone has the same problem, the response is to specify a query builder in the config file:

```
recipe:
    mappings:
        name: {boost: 100}
        chefName: {boost: 10}
        chefSurname: {boost: 10}
        bookNames: {boost: 5}
        ingredientNames: {boost: 2}
        tagNames: {boost: 2}
    persistence:
        driver: orm
        model: Interacso\ApiBundle\Entity\Recipe
        identifier: id
        provider:
                query_builder_method: buildIfIsNotDraft
        finder: ~
        listener: ~
```

And implement the specified method in the repository returning a Doctrine Query Builder. More info in the official documentation of the bundle: https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle